# TSP implementation in docplex python

Tags: python, cplex, docplex, docplexcloud

Is there any python implementation available of TSP using the IBM cplex tool, with Dantzig-Fulkerson-Johnson formulation.

If there is any can I get the link for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact same question was asked [here](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/530415/is-there-any-implementation-of-tsp-in-ibm-cplex-py.html). Here is my (slightly modified) answer from there:

The distribution does not have an example implementation in Python, but there is one in OPL: `opl/examples/opl/models/TravelingSalesmanProblem/tsp.mod` in your installation. This could serve as a good starting point when implementing things in Python.

In the example the problem is solved in a loop: after each solve, subtour elimination constraints are separated. In Python you would probably want to do this using a lazy constraint callback.

In general, subtour elimination constraints are usually not added directly to the model since there exponentially many of them.

Comment: I wanted to know how can I do lazy constraint callback to remove sub tour, that is why I am looking for implementation or something close to it.

Comment: You can find an answer to that question here: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/463342/how-to-implement-a-lazycutcallback-in-docplex.html
If that does not help/work then please ask a new question about implementing lazy constraint callbacks in `docplex`.

Comment: I have tried Implementing it by myself  But got stuck in `add_lazy_constraint` function, can you take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60543917/implementing-tsp-with-lazy-constraint-callback