# Is there a docplex function for getting solution of more than one variables for using in lazy cut?

Tags: python, optimization, docplex

I code an optimization problem in python (docplex) base on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60543917/implementing-tsp-with-lazy-constraint-callback) but my cut is something like that `sum(X) <= N + M*sum(Y, Z)`, `X, Y and Z` are decision vars. I do not know how I can pass the **solution** of `X, Y, Z` to *`self.get_cpx_unsatisfied_cts([ct],` **`solution`**`, tolerance=1e-6)`*.
when I use `self.get_values()`, I get this Error:
`Error: Internal error in CPLEX solve: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_get_var_value'`
Is there anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example [here] ([Implementing TSP with Lazy constraint callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60543917/implementing-tsp-with-lazy-constraint-callback)), callbacks are aconnected to DOcplex throught the mixin class `MosdelCallbackMixin`.
This class has a `make_complete_solution` method which returns a solution object (see documentation for docplex.mp.SolveSolution) from the callback internals.

In a second step `get_cpx_unsatisfied_cts` returns a list of unsatisfied constraints from a given list of constraints. In your case, if you need to check only one constraint, it is simpler to use the `is_satisfied` methods for constraints, which takes a solution and
a tolerance (default is 1e-6, that is:

```
   if not myct.is_satisfied(sol, tolerance):
       print(f" constraint {myct} is violated")
```

To summarize:

- use `make_complete_solution` to generate a solution object when callback is called
- use `ct.is_satisfied` to check whether is is satisfied or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering and just another question, is there any useful documentation for mixin class `MosdelCallbackMixin` ? I search a lot for it but I don't find any good document.

Comment: You're right, this class' documentation was missing. It will be documented in the soon-to-be-published version 2.16 of docplex.